# How to view the revision number of files under a folder in svn?

Tags: svn

I would like to know revision number of files under a folder, like,

```
calc/Makefile: 4
     integer.c: 4
     button.c: 5
```

How could I do this in SVN?

Comment: Do you want the revision in which they were last changed? Or is it OK to display a higher revision number if they haven't changed in those revisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `svn status -v`  or `svn status -v -u`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to output all the version numbers in the format you asked

But you can use `svn info` for each file, like:

```
svn info integer.c | grep "Last Changed Rev"
```

Or you can use `svnversion .` to get the current folder's version